# YouTube API anonymizer in C#

Tags: c#, youtube-api

Anybody knows how can I get the data from the YouTube API anonymized? Is it any option at YouTube API?

I try in the Uri variable introduce and anonymizer before the gdata but obviously it fails ¬¬

By the way, I would like to do it by code.

Comment: I chris, when using uri instance, I tried to introduce "http://anonymouse.org/cgi-bin/anon-www.cgi/" before the http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?...(I know maybe it is stupid), obviously it doesn't work and i didn't find nothing related to it in the YouTube API documentation :S

Comment: Maybe I have no explain my problem correctly. If I am in Spain my searches are related with spain terms first. I want to do "Global" searches (independent from the country you are) I know this is possible using some anonymizer webpages, but I don't know how to do by code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably rephrase your question—I believe you're asking about how to explicitly tell the YouTube API which language's results you're interested in.

You can do that with the lr=LANGUAGE_CODE query parameter, as explained at

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#lrsp

(There's no concept of "global" results, but lr=en is probably closest to what you mean.)

The restriction=COUNTRY_CODE parameter can also be relevant, but that's more about making sure that content that is unavailable in a specific country is filtered out of search results:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#restrictionsp

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to these links to get the API information:

YouTube API in C#

http://youtubeasp.codeplex.com/

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/143669/Manage-YouTube-using-C-and-Youtube-API-1-6

[Searching YouTube with the API for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567669/searching-youtube-with-the-api-for-net)

Comment: I was using https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet, sorry if I not refer :S